# selection by specific value of customDimension (BQ<>GA)

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am newbie using BiqQuery (couple of weeks experience) and trying to improve my skills. I've got a pratical question about the following very interesting query which was posted
([Recreate GA Funnel on BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45332898/recreate-ga-funnel-on-bigquery)) by user Willian Fuks. It is about GA data in BigQuery reproducing a funnel in an efficient way.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
SUM((SELECT COUNTIF(eventInfo.eventAction = 'landing_page') FROM UNNEST(hits))) Landing_Page,
SUM((SELECT COUNTIF(eventInfo.eventAction = 'model_selection_page') FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventInfo.eventAction = 'landing_page'))) Model_Selection  
FROM `64269470.ga_sessions_20170720`
```

In the example, `eventInfo.eventAction` is used. I tried several things to get it also working with `customDimension`, but I failed. Does anyone know how can I reproduce the query segmenting it with a `customDimension` instead of `eventInfo.eventAction`?

I worked with this:

```
(SELECT MAX(IF(index=1,page1, NULL))FROM UNNEST(hits.customDimensions))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `customDimensions` is a bit more challenging because this field is also an ARRAY type (repeated). Still, in practice, the main difference is that another `UNNEST` operation is required. Other than that, it's the same logic.

Here's some data to show you that:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT '1' AS fullvisitorid, 1 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'value1' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits UNION ALL

  SELECT '1' AS fullvisitorid, 2 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits UNION ALL

  SELECT '2' AS fullvisitorid, 1 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'value1' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits UNION ALL

  SELECT '3' AS fullvisitorid, 1 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(3 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits UNION ALL

  SELECT '3' AS fullvisitorid, 2 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(3 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(3 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(3 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits UNION ALL
  SELECT '4' AS fullvisitorid, 1 AS visitid, ARRAY<STRUCT< hitNumber INT64, customDimension ARRAY<STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> >  >> [STRUCT(1 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(1 AS index, 'landing_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(2 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(3 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension),
                                                                                                                                           STRUCT(3 AS hitNumber, [STRUCT(3 AS index, 'model_selection_page' AS value), STRUCT(2 AS index, 'value2' AS value)] AS customDimension)] AS hits                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
)
```

Each user (`fullvisitorid`) and each session (`visitid`) have its `hits` ARRAY. Notice I've separated each hit by its `hitNumber` which I find makes things  a bit easier to understand.

The following query computes total sessions where a `customDimension` with index 1 and value 'landing_page' happened, as well as where index was 3 and value is 'model_selection_page':

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE index = 1 AND value = 'landing_page' LIMIT 1)) Landing_Page,
  SUM((SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE index = 1 AND value = 'landing_page') AND index = 3 AND value = 'model_selection_page' LIMIT 1)) Model_Selection  
FROM
  data
```

You can play around with the simulated data to better understand what's going on here. In a nutshell, notice two `UNNEST`s happen, first to get the values inside the `hits` and the second to get the values inside `customDimension`.

The field `Model_Selection` is a bit more complex as it first has to evaluate whether the dimension 'landing_page' was fired, as you can see in this expression:

```
EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE index = 1 AND value = 'landing_page')
```

If `hits` had somewhere the 'landing_page' dimension, then this expression returns `True` in the `WHERE` clause.

You can also bring results on the user level, like so:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT (SELECT fullvisitorid FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE index = 1 AND value = 'landing_page' LIMIT 1)) Landing_Page,
  COUNT(DISTINCT (SELECT fullvisitorid FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(customDimension) WHERE index = 1 AND value = 'landing_page') AND index = 3 AND value = 'model_selection_page' LIMIT 1)) Model_Selection  
FROM
  data
```

As you are learning BigQuery, I recommend playing around with the simulated data and testing each step observing the outputs. You can play around with the `UNNEST`, run some queries testing its outputs and so on to get a better and deeper understanding of how to use these techniques.

Comment: Thanks @willianfuks for the thoroughness response! This will definitely help me a bit further in understanding it. I will also follow up your advice by playing around with the simulated data.

Comment: Just got back from (a long) holiday and I just started working with the query and simulated data. When validating the input I have noticed a small difference in Sessions from around 4% compared with the GA UI data. For Users (fullvisitorid) the data corresponds exactly. In beginning I assumed that the difference happened due to the missing hits.type, however this field can not access an Array field. Any idea what might cause this difference in Sessions?